# How can i iterate through files and active directory rights with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, active-directory

i'm a programmer student and i need to make a web application allowing to see all folders, sub folders and files and who has access to them... I also need to list active directory's groups and users and iterate through all  of server to modify them.
But i'm a c# noob and i began to learn asp.net 3 weeks ago... 
I would like to know if someone could help me by explaining how all MVC layers communicate between them.
I already have coded some functions but i don't know how to make them interact... 
Thanks for your help ! (Sorry for my bad english, i'm french... ^^')

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is really complicated for a newbie.
Since you're starting and you're using asp.net I would recommend you to start over with **ASP.NET Core** which is the new web framework built on top of .Net Core.

There are plenty of resources and courses out there. I would recommend you to get a **Pluralsight subscription**,  there are a lot of courses and they're really great, almost all of the teachers are MVP. There's a path (kinda like a carreer) for [Building ASP.NET Core Applications:](https://app.pluralsight.com/paths/skills/aspnet-core).

I've worked a few with active directory groups and users in .net core, but you'd need to understand the very basics first.

The following code consists on some methods I've used to validate users with active directory, and getting a list of all the computers inside the directory as well, but as I said you'd need to understand the basics first in order to make that code work properly inside your application

```cs
public bool ValidateWithActiveDirectory(string domainUrl, string userName, string password) {
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainUrl)) {
        UserPrincipal UserPrincipal1 = new UserPrincipal(context);
        PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(UserPrincipal1);
        foreach (UserPrincipal result in search.FindAll()) {
        }
        if (context.ValidateCredentials(userName, password)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public IEnumerable<Computer> GetActiveDirectoryComputers(string domainUrl) {
    IList<Computer> computers = new List<Computer>();
    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainUrl);
    ComputerPrincipal computerPrincipal = new ComputerPrincipal(context);
    PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(computerPrincipal);
    foreach (ComputerPrincipal result in search.FindAll()) {
        computers.Add(new Computer(result.Name));
    }
    return computers;
}
```

**Note:** If you join to [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/dev-essentials/) they'll give you 1 month free pluralsight subscription.